# setting div width dynamically

Tags: html, css

In html, displaying time(only minutes and second) along with other calculation,  when the minutes goes to the double digits then the text next to the time will disappears(like image attached). if minutes in single digit then text is visible. After time there should be a vertical text then a space and other calculation should be displayed.

```
  <div class="tab" style="left: 187px; top: 25px; width: 50px; text-align: right; color: ${}"><span class="start-time">${}</span><span class="text-vertical  cc-gray">Start</span></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Increase the width to another `5px` or decrease the `font` size by `2`.

Comment: Share the working code(minimal reproducible code) to help you.

Comment: Why set the width at all? HTML elements naturally adjust to their contents. Set `display: inline-block` and let it size itself.

Comment: @rayhatfield your solution works as expected , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try the following! Hope it helps

```html
<div class="tab" style="width: auto; text-align: center; padding: 10px; color: ${}">
  <span class="start-time">${}</span>
  <span class="text-vertical cc-gray">Start</span>
</div>
```